# Simple way to reformat a large(ish) XML file?

Tags: mysql, xml, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to build a store locator that uses data from an XML file to load the locations.

The current file is set out such as below, once exported from phpmyadmin:

```
<table name="tblLabs">
<column name="LabID">76</column>
<column name="RegionID">8</column>
<column name="Consultant">Dr M E Herd</column>
<column name="BMS">Mrs C Pickup</column>
<column name="AP">NULL</column>
<column name="AdditionalStaff">NULL</column>
<column name="Department">Pathology Dept</column>
<column name="OrganizationName">Bury General Hospital</column>
<column name="Address">Walmersley Road</column>
<column name="Address1">Bury</column>
<column name="City">Lancs</column>
<column name="PostCode">BL9 6PG</column>
<column name="Tel">0161 1234 1234</column>
<column name="Fax">0161 1234 1234</column>
<column name="EMail">email@email.com</column>
<column name="Comments"></column>
<column name="Public">1</column>
<column name="lat">0.000000</column>
<column name="lng">0.000000</column>
<column name="type"></column>
</table>
```

For it to work with the javascript file I need it to be formated as below:

```
<markers>

<marker Consultant="Dr M E Herd" 
BMS="Mrs C Pickup" 
AP="NULL" 
AdditionalStaff="NULL" 
Department="Pathology Dept" 
name="Bury General Hospital" 
address="Walmersley Road" 
city="Bury" 
state="Lancs" 
postal="BL9 6PG" 
phone="0161 705 3274" 
Fax="0161 705 3418" 
email="email@email.com" 
Comments="" 
lat="53.6145706" 
lng="-2.2927511" 
type="" />

</markers>
```

Is there a way I can export from phpmyadmin in the format as above? Or is there another way I can quickly reformat the data as to the way I need it? I also need to add in lat & lng from a batch geocode service I am using.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done rather easily with this [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="table">
        <markers>
            <marker>
                <xsl:for-each select="column">
                    <xsl:attribute name="{@name}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </marker>
        </markers>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can test it [online](http://xslt.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php).

This does not add the latitude and longitude, though - but why aren't you storing this in MySQL?